# Excel VBA user-form update button

Tags: vba, excel

Update button works if there is value in cells beside the target cell
can not find the problem in this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim irow As Long, _
wS As Worksheet, _
NextRow As Long, _
cF As Range
Set wS = Worksheets("stock")
With wS
    With .Range("A:A")

        Set cF = .Find(What:=Me.ComboBox2.value, _
                After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)
    End With

 If Not cF Is Nothing Then
    If cF.Offset(0, 1) <> vbNullString Then
        Set cF = cF.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 25)
        cF.value = Me.TextBox2.value + .Cells(cF.row, "AA").value
    End If
 Else
   .Cells(cF.row, "AA").value = Me.TextBox2.value + .Cells(cF.row,   "AA").value
 End If
```

End With
 End Sub

if Target cell is AA2 then there should be value in  Z2 or B2 otherwise nothing happens.

Just added ELSE statement but with else its updating value in Column AB not in AA

[image: form]

Comment: I am not expert but i think your condition or something to do in IF code

Comment: I see two `with` but only one `end with` statements

Comment: Your code is specifically set to NOT update if the cell next to the target cell is blank: `If cF.Offset(0, 1) <> vbNullString Then` so you'll either need to add an `Else` statement, or remove that condition.

Comment: @GôTô that is not missing in real code only error here but its updated

Comment: I know i am doing some basic mistake

Comment: That final If statement... `If Not cF is Nothing Then`.  In the `Else`, where `cF` is Nothing, you are referring to `cF.Row`?

Comment: _"with else its updating value in Column AB not in AA"_ : are you sure? It looks to me that AB column is grabbed by "Set cF = cF.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 25)". But I can't grasp your goal: maybe you want to edit question adding examples of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that just on basis of hit n trial and it works

```
   `Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim irow As Long, _
    wS As Worksheet, _
    NextRow As Long, _
   cF As Range
   Set wS = Worksheets("stock")
   With wS
   With .Range("A:A")

    Set cF = .Find(What:=Me.ComboBox2.value, _
            After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            SearchFormat:=False)

 .Cells(cF.row, "AA").value = Me.TextBox2.value + .Cells(cF.row,   "AA").value
 End With
 End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the following codes :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click() 'Change Button
Dim sonsat As Long

If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "Choose an item", vbExclamation, ""
Exit Sub
End If
lastrow = Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Data").Range("A2:A" & lastrow).Find(What:=ListBox1.Text, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Activate
sonsat = ActiveCell.Row
Cells(sonsat, 1) = TextBox1.Text
Cells(sonsat, 2) = TextBox2.Text
Cells(sonsat, 3) = TextBox3.Text
Cells(sonsat, 4) = TextBox4.Text
Cells(sonsat, 5) = TextBox5.Text
Cells(sonsat, 6) = TextBox6.Text
Cells(sonsat, 7) = TextBox7.Text
Cells(sonsat, 8) = TextBox8.Text
Cells(sonsat, 9) = TextBox9.Text
Cells(sonsat, 10) = TextBox10.Text
Cells(sonsat, 11) = TextBox11.Text
Cells(sonsat, 12) = TextBox12.Text
Cells(sonsat, 13) = TextBox16
Cells(sonsat, 14) = TextBox17
Cells(sonsat, 15) = TextBox18

Call Main 'Progress Bar
MsgBox "Item has been updated", vbApplicationModal, ""
ListBox1.List = Sheets("Data").Range("A2:O" & Sheets("Data").Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
End Sub
```

Userform codes (data insert, delete, update, search by column data, listbox with 15 columns, data copy, progressbar) ,you can review from this [source](https://www.technologicaltipstools.online/2016/11/new-updated-userform-15-column-more.html).